# General Tree Post Order Traversal

Tags: javascript, tree, tree-traversal, postorder

```
var tree = {
  "name" : "root",
  "children" : [
    {
      "name" : "first child",
      "children" : [
        {
          "name" : "first child of first",
          "children" : []
        },
        {
          "name" : "second child of first",
          "children" : []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "second child",
      "children" : []
    }
  ]
}

function postOrder(root) {
  if (root == null) return;

  postOrder(root.children[0]);
  postOrder(root.children[1]);

  console.log(root.name);
}

postOrder(tree);
```

Heres my code for a recursive post order traversal in javascript using a JSON tree.

How would I go about adapting this code to handle N children in a node?

Comment: Have you tried something like `for (child in root.children) postOrder(root.children[child])`?

Comment: @Tibrogargan defiantly works! Thanks! but I think i much prefer the "forEach" as suggested below :)

Comment: So do I.  My brain keeps expecting Javascript's `for .. in` construct to work the same as in other languages, forEach is cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want: just replace your calls to `postOrder` with `root.children.forEach(postOrder);`.

```js
var tree = {
  "name" : "root",
  "children" : [
    {
      "name" : "first child",
      "children" : [
        {
          "name" : "first child of first",
          "children" : []
        },
        {
          "name" : "second child of first",
          "children" : []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "second child",
      "children" : []
    }
  ]
}

function postOrder(root) {
  if (root == null) return;

  root.children.forEach(postOrder);

  console.log(root.name);
}

postOrder(tree);
```

I'd also move the line that prints the `root` name before the call that prints the children names recursively, but this may not match your use case.

Comment: Perfect!! thanks a lot! i knew it had to be done iteratively at this point but my knowledge of javascript is poor at the moment, the forEach is a trick i shall keep in my books Thanks!